# Show Woocommerce Product "attributes/extra information tab" in widget

Tags: widgets, plugins

I have a question concerning WP in combination with WooCommerce, I hope someone can help me out.

When viewing a product on the site I would like the "extra information tab" (containing all the attributes I added to the product) to be showed in a widget next to the product description (via a sidebar in the theme) instead of them showing as a seperate tab underneath the product photo.

I'm guessing I would need to add a widget with a custom hook/filter or something to display the product attributes?

Could anyone help me out here? Would be greatly appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the `content-single-product.php` WooCommerce template for an idea of what functions are hooked where. It is very well commented. 
The following should remove the additional info from the tabs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpa_116999_remove_info' );
function wpa_116999_remove_info( $tabs ){
  unset($tabs['additional_information']); 
  return $tabs;
}
```

And then wherever you'd like to add the Additional Info you'll just need to called the `woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab()` function. I wouldn't bother registering a widget. Depending on your theme you can either add it to a relavent hook in your functions.php, or create a child theme and paste it directly into `sidebar-shop.php` or `sidebar.php`.  It is hard to be precise on this point because every theme is so different, but that's the general idea.

In your functions.php, editing the fictional `sometheme_before_sidebar` hook to an appropriate hook for your theme:

```
if(function_exists('woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab'))
     add_action('sometheme_before_sidebar', 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab');
```

or directly in the child theme's sidebar.php file:

```
if(function_exists('woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab'))
    woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab();
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little over my head here.

I managed to remove the additional tabs by adding the first bit of code to content-single-product.php in my theme's child folder.

But I'm afraid I can't get the remaining bit to work. If I add those lines to my functions.php or sidebar file nothing seems to happen...

I guess I have to change "sometheme" to the theme name, but that also doesn't help. I'm probably doing something wrong, but what... :) :(

Comment: Yes, `sometheme_before_sidebar` is a fictional hook. I can't tell you the appropriate hook for your theme (if there is one) because I don't know what theme you are using and every theme is different. I made an error transcribing the function name. I will edit to correct.